# Cache Web Application files locally (for responsiveness)

Tags: web-applications

is there a way i can cache all required application files on the local computer for speed without any disruption (at least those that can be run locally)?

i want it to be able to start even without connection right from the start, isit possible? is Google Gears what i shld use? i heard theres a HTML5 feature/module for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Gears is being phased out; avoid it like the plague.

On the other hand, HTML 5 has an identical feature that lets you do offline support for your app (basically offline caching). Check out the docs for this feature:

http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/

Basically, you declare a manifest file that describes all of the resources required to make your application available without an internet connection. When the browser authorizes offline support, the files are downloaded and stored. If I'm not mistaken, there's also ways to set how often the files are refreshed/re-downloaded.

Hope this helps!